# Finding Fundamental Matrix of Differential Equations with Periodic Coefficients

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

So I am supposed to find the fundamental matrix of

$x'_1=(1+2\cos(2t))x_1+(1-2\sin(2t))x_2$

$x'_2=-(1+2\sin(2t)x_1+(1-2\cos(2t))x_2$

The book suggests using the transformation $x=Q(t)\hat{x}$ where $Q=\begin{bmatrix} \cos(t) & \sin(t) \\ -\sin(t) & \cos(t) \end{bmatrix} $

The fundamental matrix should be $ X(t)=\begin{bmatrix} e^{3t}\cos(t) & e^{-t}\sin(t) \\ -e^{3t}\sin(t) &e^{-t}\cos(t) \end{bmatrix}$

So, I understand that this conversion points towards finding $\hat{x}$ (turning the problem $x'=A(t)x \implies (Q(t)\hat{x})'=A(t)Q(t)\hat{x}$), but I am unsure how to go about solving. Based on the form I see in the solution, is this transformation supposed to give a matrix of constant coefficients whose eigenvalues would be $\lambda=-1,3$ and use that method? I just need a few first steps to help out. Thanks for any assistance